# Recommended partitioning strategy Windows Server 2022

Tags: hyper-v, diskmanagement, windows-server-2022

I’m setting up a Windows Server 2022 machine and was wondering about partitioning strategies. I will be using the server for Terminal Services (2 or 3 users) and Hyper-V. Running maybe 12 or so VM’s. The VM’s will be database servers mostly for testing. The machine will have 128GB RAM and 12 Cores. I have a 1TB NVME, a 500GB NVME, a 500GB SATA SSD and a 250GB SATA SSD. How would you set this out for the OS, VM’s, data etc.?

Would you create the VM’s on a separate drive? Would you partition the 1TB? Any other recommendations. It’s been a minute since I set up a server.

Comment: Such a hogpog of different drives is virtually useless. Get two sets of identical drives, one to set up as RAID1 for the system (250 GB max) and one as RAID1 for the data. No need for special partitioning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: I put this server together from what I had. Not buying any more disks. Real question is all around partitioning of what I have now.